# LPM reboot Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: reboot, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I'm trying to have my Samsung Galaxy S7 phone start up into normal operation when USB power comes on. I have tested all the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169387/how-to-make-android-device-boot-when-power-is-plugged-in) and several others, but whatever I do the phone will not reboot into normal operation. My result is no reboot or reboot into Recovery mode.

I have also tested several ROMs with same result. There seems to be a problem when the `\system\bin\reboot` is called in LPM (Low Power Mode) mode.

Script:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/lpm_orig &
while [ true ]; do
  sleep 1
  ps | grep lpm_orig && sleep 3 && /system/bin/reboot
done
```

(The "lpm_orig" is the original lpm file). Linux owner and execution rights have been checked. Does anyone have an idea what to try next?

Answer (score 3):

This has been hell to figure out. Might as well put it out here to help anyone else googling around.

For the Samsung Galaxy S7, first the script:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

# Script to reboot the system as soon as the charger is inserted
# https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/android-trusty-3.10/Documentation/sysrq.txt

# Enable kernel commands.
su -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq"

# Send an immediate reboot request.
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

And to install it, you first backup and replace the /system/bin/lpm file.
As OP already mentioned, replacing the file will cause it not to work (explained [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s7/help/samsung-galaxy-s7-boot-charge-t3680083))

The inode (file unique identifier) of the lpm file has to remain the same before Android will accept it, so instead we have to replace the *contents* of the existing file.

That's easily enough done:

```
echo /system/bin/lpm > /system/bin/lpm.bak
```

And dump our script code into it:

```
echo /sdcard/reboot_on_charge.sh > /system/bin/lpm
```

Of course this will require root, and to remount the system folder as read-write:

```
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
```

And that's it! That's how I got this to work for the S7.

Undoing the changes should be as simple as doing:

```
cat /system/bin/lpm.bak > /system/bin/lpm
rm /system/bin/lpm.bak
```

Edit:
 - To add an extra detail, make sure the file is using Linux (LF) line endings as opposed to CR_LF (Windows). My git repo switched them out from under me and I was left debugging why the phone suddenly started going to recovery mode again when it reboots.

Comment: I try to run scripts. But have read only error.

Comment: @Konrad Did you remember to mount your system partition as read-write? You have to do this before it will let you install the scripts.
`mount -o rw,remount /system`